# Mule ESB, does the payload need to be in any particular format for the Load and Dispatch phase during batch processing?

Tags: batch-processing, mule-esb

In regards to [Mule ESB batch processing](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/batch-processing):

For the Load and Dispatch phase, what format does the payload need to be in? I have a large xml file that I would like to batch process. Does it need any type of transformation before the Load and Dispatch phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it in Anypoint Studio and got the following exception:

```
Object "org.mule.transport.file.ReceiverFileInputStream" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}"
```